# Оптимизация отрисовки матрицы

Tags: javascript, canvas, оптимизация

### Задача

Есть у меня класс цветов - `Color` и матрица из цветов `board`.
Матрица состоит всего из несколько цветов, эти цвета мы имеем в `colors`.
Мне надо отрисовать матрицу в каждом кадре на `CanvasRenderingContext2D`. Функция обновления в каждом кадре уже есть.

### Что я пробовал

1. Отрисовка самым банальным способом

```js
for (let y = 0; y < board.size.y; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < board.size.x; x++) {
        const position = new Point2D(x, y);
        const color = board.get(position);
        context.fillStyle = color.toString();
        context.fillRect(position.x * sizeCell.x, position.y * sizeCell.y, sizeCell.x, sizeCell.y);
    }
}
```

2. Отрисовка каждого цвета отдельно

```js
for (const color of colors) {
    context.beginPath();
    for (let y = 0; y < board.size.y; y++) {
        for (let x = 0; x < board.size.x; x++) {
            const position = new Point2D(x, y);
            const color2 = board.get(position);
            if (color == color2) {
                context.rect(position.x * sizeCell.x, position.y * sizeCell.y, sizeCell.x, sizeCell.y);
            }
        }
    }
    context.fillStyle = color.toString();
    context.fill();
}
```

Другие, более сложные алгоритмы тоже в голову приходили, но я не смог их реализовать.

### Проблема

Для матрицы 100 на 100 FPS падает до 40 для обоих способов. Я понимаю, что отрисовать матрицу 100 × 100 в каждом кадре не простая задача, но я уверен, что это дело можно оптимизировать как минимум до 70-90 FPS.

### Вопрос

Какими способами можно оптимизировать отрисовку? Как изменить текущие алгоритмы, или может посоветуйте получше что-то?

Comment: Чему равны `sizeCell.x`, `sizeCell.y`?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy это размеры одной ячейки. Считается по уравнению `new Point2D(canvas.width / board.size.x, canvas.height / board.size.y)`

Comment: 90 FPS означает, что вы на скриптовом языке собрались за секунду обрабатывать 900000 операций копирования цвета. Это довольно оптимистично. Ищите другой способ обновлять изображение.

Comment: на сколько часто обновляются поля? Можно отрисовать поле в картинку и выводить сразу всю картинку

Comment: @Grundy примерно раз в 4-12 кадров.

Comment: добавь больше информации о том что именно меняется и как. Скорее всего достаточно будет перерисовывать только измененные клетки

Comment: @Grundy каждый из цветов имеет свои особенности. Каждый из них проверяет ближайшие 8 ячеек и при наличии заданного цвета выполняет какую-то функцию. Подробнее чтобы рассказать придется рассказать весь скрипт целиком.

Comment: @Grundy разве что могу показать. Взгляните [на это](https://eccs0103.github.io/Elements/).

Comment: храни отдельно цвета и рисуй их отдельно. В итоге получится один большой квадрат с фоном, и несколько маленьких картинок с цветами которые рисуются поверх

Comment: @Grundy на данный момент [так и сделал](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yOvE.png). FPS колеблется среди 50-70, но выглядит лучше.

Comment: Я имел ввиду немного другое - ты в своем варианте все равно бежишь по всей таблице

Comment: @Grundy понял. Ловить изменения и рисовать их, верно? Слишком запутан на данный момент код, но этот вариант так же попробую скоро.